# spring boot 1.5 single sign on Authorization Server Failed to process import candidates for configuration class

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm building sso authorization server by using `spring boot 1.5` but resource server  and client are using `spring boot 2.0`

Everything looks good via my local things run well. But when I try to deploy the war file on tomcat server.

We've faced the problem as below:

```
Failed to process import candidates for configuration class
[org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration];
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/springframework/boot/context/properties/bind/Bindable
```

I guess it is due to the mix between `spring boot 1.5` and `2.0`

Please help me.

Thank!

Comment: We fixed it by ourself by using sprint boot 2.0 for both auth server and resource server.

Comment: I am having the same problem. using spring-boot embedded tomcat. could you share the .pom?